# Complex domain graphs

Tags: graph, exponential

[image]

Source of image : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144268/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-plot-function-on-complex-plane-vs-time-shown

I had in one of my lectures a graph of how sin, cos and exp are related in complex domain with a figure that close to that one. I searched on-line a lot until I found that picture on Math.SE.

As per my search I found that it is only PTC mathcad that is stating it is possible to draw complex domain graphs but couldn't find any information related in mathcad manual or even in books including such graphs. Did any one managed to have such graphs drawn before. I would appreciate it as it will help me imagine graphically the circulation of complex numbers and the changes in formulas.

Can any one help?

Comment: The user wished to draw a particular type of image and what actions they had taken to identify the tool used to draw it, narrowing it down to Mathcad, but were uncertain from their research whether Mathcad could, in fact, create such an image.   Consequently, as the user has described the problem and what they had done so far to solve it, I interpret this to be a specific request for information on *using* a given tool, and not as a general request for such a tool.   The answer that I gave addresses this, and is neither a matter of opinion nor spam.  Please withdraw your objection.

Comment: @Stuart: then edit the question to improve it; as it stands it asks for tutorials or tools.

Comment: @MartijnPieters replaced tutorial by information, and removed tools as I already did the work to find that there is only one tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mathcad, use CreateSpace with the appropriate functions of time.  You'll have to open the plot dialog box to set the various axis and backplane options. You'll also need to ensure that each of the 3 plot elements is set to Data Points rather than Surface (the default display for the 3D plot component).

[image]

I typed the plot's expressions for exp, sin and cos elsewhere in the worksheet and then dragged them onto the plot.